# java: how to apply the right charset to java string

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

i have two chinese words "果然有问题", which is encoded in GB3212.
However, it is wrongly encoded into ANSI and become "彆衄恀枙".
With hex editor, it is B9FBC8BBD3D0CECACCE2

I would like to use java to correct the charset and store it to UTF-16.

So, I try to:

```
            String wrongstr = "彆衄恀枙";
            byte[] binary = wrongstr.getBytes("BIG5");
            System.out.printf("%s", new String(binary, "GB2312"));
```

but what I get is: 果?有问题

I used Notepad++ and can see the correct word. I cannot use getBytes("BIG5") or getBytes("US_ANSI") or r.getBytes("GB2312") to get the correct hex (B9FBC8BBD3D0CECACCE2)

[image]

I dont know what is wrong. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there *any* possibility of getting at the original data instead? Those Chinese characters simply aren't present in any ANSI-compatible encoding I'm aware of (and certainly not ASCII). It's not really clear what you *have* got, but it's not right... where did this data come from?

Comment: i used notepad++, the text is GB3212, but the txt format is stored as ANSI, so it format is wrong, how can i correct the wrong word in JAVA? thanks

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about what encodings really are. It can't be both GB3212 and ANSI... and ANSI isn't one single encoding, but a whole range of encodings which are compatible with ASCII for the first 127 characters. What *creates* the file in the first place? If you're creating it in Notepad++, I suggest you just save it as UTF-8 and use that when reading it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that was not ANSI, it has no chineese characters. Big5, however, does:

```
String wrongstr = "湖馱";
byte[] binary = wrongstr.getBytes("Big5");
System.out.printf("%s", new String(binary, "GB2312"));
```

So this code snippet gives the result you want.

Comment: sorry i used a poor example, i updated my question. please help, thank

Comment: That's a bit different story now. Do you see a question mark as a second symbol of the "damaged text"? That's because Big5 has no mapping for C8BB. And the big5-encoder replaced the unknown byte sequence with a question mark to indicate the error. After that noone can figure out what was standing on the second position before the wrong encoding, information is lost. Your trick with Notepad++ works only because it's working with the initial data, unlike your java code. So you can't reair the data this way from java code.